# Fill the entire form based on selection (onchange)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an ingredient form and I want the user to type only the name and then the carb, protein and fat get automatically loaded. I know I need an ajax request but I don't know the path to learn how to accomplish this.
Can anyone gives an example or tell me where I can find it?

Comment: Btw, should I spend time learning js? I know the basics and some advised me not to learn in depth due to the amount of plugins already available...

Comment: Do you know AJAX and Javascript/jQuery already?

Comment: Yes, they are basically the same. Ajax is for client side and so independent of server side languages.

Comment: I know a few things, enough to adapt some codes to what I want... I'll spend a few days learning it :) thanks, folks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn Jquery too. Jquery is a widely used Javascript library and you will find a lot of help too.

Coming back to the question, **$ajax** method will be used to send an ajax request from your .js file. You will find a lot of documentation on it.

If you want to send an ajax request using rails helpers and views use the

```
remote : true
```

option. it will process your request as a **XmlHttpRequest** one. You can check the type of request by naigating to your browsers console and see the type of request. In case of Ajax request it will be **XmlHttpRequest** type.

This is not a thorough answer since you will find a lot of documentation on internet. But just to get you started.

Comment: Great! What is the path this 'remote' request does? I mean, is the same as a 'get' or 'post'? First find the action then hit the database? I found libraries and documentations about ajax, not about its relation with rails. Thanks for your time and help.